# Understanding the Analytic Continuation of the Gamma Function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

So my book proves the convergence of $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ in the right half plane $Re(z) > 0$, and then goes on to prove the initial recurrence relation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ by applying integration by parts to $\Gamma(z+1)$:

$$\int_0^{\infty}t^{z}e^{-t}dt = -t^ze^{-t}|_0^{\infty} + z\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$$

The book explicitly states this equality to be true only in the right half plane, since otherwise $-t^ze^{-t}|_0^{\infty} = \infty$, instead of equaling zero.  With this initial recurrence relation we are 'supposably' able to analytically continue the Gamma function to $Re(z) > -1$ (not including the origin) by writing the relation in the form:

$$\Gamma(z) = \frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$$

What I don't understand is this relation is still only true in the right half plane, since otherwise $-t^ze^{-t}|_0^{\infty}\neq 0$.  I don't see what reason we have to believe that, for instance, $\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Furthermore $\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ is clearly not convergent in the left half plane, so I can't even imagine why it would be plausible to think that a recurrence relation directly based on it could possibly lead to a genuine analytic continuation of its domain.

Comment: One lateral application of this analytic cont. formula is that we get $$\lim_{z\to 0}z\Gamma(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\Gamma(z+1)=\Gamma(1)=1$$which gives the residue of $\,\Gamma(z)\,$ at $\,z=0\,$ . Appying this to all the negatative integers you find quite a curious and nice formula for the function's residues there...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you have said, $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ does not even make sense on the left half plane.

However, if we define $\Gamma(z) = \dfrac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ on the left half plane, (and this is not equal to the integral above on the left half plane), this is consistent with the fact that $\Gamma(z) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ on the right half plane and also provides us a possible extension on the left half plane except at negative integers.

Further, this has to be the *only* analytic continuation since $\Gamma(z) = \dfrac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ is analytic everywhere except at negative integers and matches with the integral on the right half plane and hence by uniqueness of analytic continuation this is the only possible extension.

**EDIT**

To see that the extension, is in fact analytic except at negative integers, you proceed strip by strip. On the right half plane, you have $\Gamma(z)$ defined by the integral, $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1} \exp(-t) dt$. You can verify that the integral satisfies the functional equation and is in fact analytic.

We will now extend the function to the strip corresponding to $(-1,0)$ i.e. the strip $\text{Re}(z) \in (-1,0)$ based on the functional equation.

Define $\Gamma(z) = \dfrac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ on the strip $\text{Re}(z) \in (-1,0)$.

First note that $\Gamma(z+1)$ is analytic on the strip $\text{Re}(z) \in (-1,0)$ since $z+1 \in$ right half plane. Also, $\dfrac1z$ is analytic on the strip $\text{Re}(z) \in (-1,0)$. Hence, $\Gamma(z) = \dfrac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ is analytic on the strip $\text{Re}(z) \in (-1,0)$. Hence, now we have extended the definition of the $\Gamma$ function to the region $\text{Re}(z) > -1$.

Now repeat the same argument for the strip $\text{Re}(z) \in (-2,-1)$, since we now have that the $\Gamma$-function is analytic on the region  $\text{Re}(z) > -1$. And so on...

Comment: @zyx There is at-most one analytic extension of $f(z) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt$.

Comment: To be slightly more precise, you first define $\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)/z$ on $\{z: \text{Re}(z) > -1\} \backslash \{0\}$, observing that this agrees with the previous definition on the right half plane.  Then you define it in $\{z: \text{Re}(z) > -2\} \backslash \{-1,0\}$ ...

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes. Thanks. I have written that as a comment to Gerry's answer. (In the comment, I need to change the interval from $(-1,0)$ to the corresponding strip.) I will add this to my answer soon.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your third paragraph was asserting unique analytic continuation of the factorial, not of the integral used to define gamma on the right half plane.

Answer (score 5):

The recurrence is used to *define* Gamma in places where the integral doesn't work. What's needed is to prove that a function defined that way is analytic; then it follows that it's *the* analytic continuation of Gamma.

Comment: To prove that it's analytic for complex numbers with a negative real part.. But how? and I still don't see why anyone would think that it would be, a priori, that is.

Comment: @NollieTré You go interval by interval to see it is analytic except on negative integers. In the interval $(-1,0)$, do you see that $\Gamma(z) = \dfrac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ is analytic? If so, then proceed next to interval $(-2,-1)$. And so on.

Comment: Ohhhh ok I see it now! thanks =]

Answer (score 4):

An excellent introduction to this topic can be found in the book
[The Gamma Function](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/149377543X) by James Bonnar. An entire chapter is devoted to analytic continuation of the factorials, as well as why the Gamma function is defined as it is -- Hölder's theorem and the Bohr-Mullerup theorem are discussed.

Comment: `Here you can get a free version from 2017 updated: http://vixra.org/abs/1702.0305` - [Ameyah](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/408929/ameyah)