# Is $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$ valid for every $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots\}$?

Tags: gamma-function

I know that this is valid for every $s$ in the half plane $\{s:\operatorname{Re}(s)>0\}$, but does the formula extend along with the analytic continuation of the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: Yessir, it sure does!

Comment: See (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159333/understanding-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-gamma-function)

Comment: If two analytic functions coincide on a set that has an accumulation point, then they're equal.